# ApiController get with id not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I just started working with `ApiController`. I'm trying to do an HTTP GET sending an ID, but it is not working.

My ApiController:

```
[Route("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private myEntity db = new myEntity();

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
    {
        // Get a list of customers
        IEnumerable<Customer> customers = db.Customers.ToList();

        // Write the list of customers to the response body
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customers);

        return response;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetById(int id)
    {
        // Get Customer by id
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        if (customer == null)
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return response;
        } else
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customer);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

When I run it in the browser, the `GetAll` method work perfectly. However, when I try `GetById`:

```
http://localhost:53198/api/Test/1
```

It returns:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI `http://localhost:53198/api/Test/1`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your URL is not correct: `http://localhost:53198/api/Test/GetById/1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using attribute routing you would need to make a few changes to make sure that action routes are distinct to avoid any route conflicts.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController {
    private myEntity db = new myEntity();

    //GET api/Test
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll() {
        // Get a list of customers
        var customers = db.Customers.ToList();    
        // Write the list of customers to the response body
        return OK(customers);
    }

    //GET api/Test/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id) {
        // Get Customer by id
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (customer == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(customer);
    }
}
```

This assumes that attribute routing is enabled

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: RoutePrefix it works. However, if I send an id that is not in the database it just gives me a empty page in the browsers, not the NotFound status

Comment: You will have to redactor the function to return not found. On phone right now. Will update when I get back to my machine.

Comment: Thanks... I'm waiting. Idk what "redactor the function" is

Comment: @MaxBoy check update using the advised syntax from documentation.

Comment: Thanks... I replaced my code to use NotFound(); but it did not change anything. When I do a get request with an ID that does not exists, it just returns a blank page. I mean, it does not return a NotFound error/warning

Answer (score 2):

You can do either

- `http://localhost:53198/api/Test/GetById/1` (as DavidG mentioned)

or

- http://localhost:53198/api/Test/1 
  and changing your code to

  ```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("{id:int}")]
  public HttpResponseMessage GetById(int id)
  ```

Comment: Adding the [Route("{id:int}")] did not work for me. Same error

Comment: @MaxBoy Can you update your question with content of WebApiConfig class

Comment: Adding RoutePrefix it works. However, if I send an id that is not in the database it just gives me a empty page in the browsers, not the NotFound status

Comment: @MaxBoy You have to return 404 if you don't find record with that Id in your db, it doesn't do it automatically for you

Comment: Hum... I tried to do it using response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); Is it wrong?

Comment: @MaxBoy `return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)`